# No se visualizan los iconos fontawesome, estoy trabajando con angular

Tags: angular, font-awesome, vscode

estoy trabajando en angular, trato de incluir unos iconos personales en icomoon, descargue fontawesome y en la carpeta css/ coloqué fontawesome.css y fontawesome.min y con lo que respecta a los nuevos iconos también los llamé. este es mi ejemplo:

El problema es que no se ven los iconos que antes ya había llamado desde fontawesome, lo que quería era actualizar los iconos, pero, no se que paso, porque ya no se ven.

```
<!doctype html>
```

```
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>jfkji</title>

  <meta name="description" content="jfkji Template">

  <!-- base url -->
  <base href="/">


  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">


  <!-- #CSS Links -->
  <!-- Basic Styles -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="assets/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="assets/css/font-aicos.css">


  <!-- SmartAdmin Styles : Caution! DO NOT change the order -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="assets/css/smartadmin-production-plugins.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="assets/css/smartadmin-production.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="assets/css/smartadmin-skins.min.css">

  <!-- SmartAdmin RTL Support (Not using RTL? Disable the CSS below to save bandwidth) -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="assets/css/smartadmin-rtl.min.css">

  <!-- Smartadmin Angular 5. Flex Layout  -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="assets/css/smartadmin-angular-next.css">

  <!-- Demo purpose only: goes with demo.js, you can delete this css when designing your own WebApp -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="assets/css/demo.min.css">

  <!-- #FAVICONS -->
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/img/favicon/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">


  <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.7.0/standard-all/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logré visualizar todos los iconos gracias a un link, creo, se debe al tipo de versiones.

El link que agregué dentro de `<header>` es el siguiente:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Espero que a alguien con un problema parecido, también le pueda servir.